# How come Ajax response is different?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can't find the reason why my ajax response is different when I console.log the response. Any ideas?
Page1 is used in account update form while page2 is used in registration form.

page1.js:

```
function ajaxCheckDupEmail(){
    if(valid_email === true){
        return $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajax/page1.php',
            data:{ 'email': email, 'email_login': email_login },
            success:function(response){
                //some code
            }
        });
    }else{
        //other code
    }
}

$.when(ajaxCheckDupEmail()).done(function(a1){
    console.log(a1);
    if(a1[0] === 'false'){
        //submitting form
        //some code
    }
});
```

NOTE: email and email_login is a js var where I store userinput in, I used valid_email to check if email is valid

page1.php:

```
if(isset($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["email"])){
$email = trim_strip_data($_POST["email"]);
$email_login = trim_strip_data($_POST["email_login"]);

$prep_data_email = $db->prepare("SELECT email FROM user WHERE email = :email");
$prep_data_email->execute(array(":email" => $email));
$row_count = $prep_data_email->rowCount();
if($row_count === 1 && $email !== $email_login){
    echo "true";
}else{
    echo "false";
}
}
```

NOTE: trim_strip_data() is a custom function to trim white spaces although I don't think it is necessary in this case

page2.js:

```
function ajaxCheckDupEmail(){
    if(valid_email === true){
        return $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajax/page2.php',
            data:{ 'email': email },
            success:function(response){
                // some code
            }
        });
    }else{
        //other code
    }
}

function ajaxCheckDupUsername(){
    if(username !== ""){
        return $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajax/page2.php',
            data:{ 'username': username },
            success:function(response){
                // some code
            }
        });
    }else{
        //other code
    }
}

$.when(ajaxCheckDupUsername(), ajaxCheckDupEmail()).done(function(a1, a2){
    console.log(a1);
    console.log(a2);
    if(a1[0] === 'false' && a2[0] === 'false'){
        //submitting form
        //some code
    }
});
```

NOTE: email is a js var where I store userinput in, I used valid_email to check if email is valid

page2.php:

```
if(isset($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["email"])){
$email = trim_strip_data($_POST["email"]);

$prep_data_email = $db->prepare("SELECT email FROM user WHERE email = :email");
$prep_data_email->execute(array(":email" => $email));
$row_count = $prep_data_email->rowCount();
if($row_count === 1){
    echo "true";
}else{
    echo "false";
}
}

if(isset($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["username"])){
$username = trim_strip_data($_POST["username"]);

$prep_data_username = $db->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username");
$prep_data_username->execute(array(":username" => $username));
$row_count = $prep_data_username->rowCount();
if($row_count === 1){
    echo "true";
}else{
    echo "false";
}
}
```

NOTE: trim_strip_data() is a custom function to trim white spaces although I don't think it is necessary in this case

The problem is I get 2 different response results (depending on result true/false).

In page1.js I get:

```
true
```

In page2.js I get:

```
true,success,[object Object]

true,success,[object Object]
```

It looks like I get an response object in page2.js but why I don't get one in page1.js?

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/#jQuery-when-deferreds

You are dealing with promises, and a promise always returns a promise.
So I would double check page1 isn't returning the object too.

E.g. open dev tools and run the following;

```
$.when().done(function( x ) {  alert('done')});
```

you will see it returns an object, this is the promise.

but for

```
true,success,[object Object]
```

I don't see where `success` is coming from, are you missing some code?

On a side note...

```
if(valid_email === true)
```

is the same as

```
if(valid_email)
```

sorry, it was just bugging me.

Comment: I alerted the two responses but I get the same results as stated in my question. I'm not missing any code.